# TabLayout - selected tab with different font

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-fonts

Is there any way to set a different font on the tab that is currently selected (in TabLayout) ?

To use custom fonts I use Calligraphy, but I am looking for any way to define different font for the currently selected tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabLayout` is a `ViewGroup` so you can access its children with `getChildAt(selectedPosition)`. Then you can iterate over `TabItem` children (as by default its `LinearLayout` containing single `ImageView` and single `TextView`) and if you find a `TextView` instance execute `TextView.setTypeface()` passing desired font as an argument.

Comment: Ok - but a "new tab is selected" listener is needed. How to capture change tab action?

Comment: You can add a `TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) method.